# UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL when uploading from iOS to PHP backend

Tags: php, ios

I have an iOS app that is uploading images to a PHP backend using NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequests, the usual.

Every once in a while, but with seeming regularity, we're getting UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL PHP upload errors when images are uploaded from devices to the server. Now I suppose some of the time it could be due to loss/degradation of signal on people's phones and such. But I did some research and it seems these errors can be caused by issues with headers, e.g. Keep-Alive (see http://www.bizzeh.com/739/php-problem-with-upload_err_partial-file-upload-error-code-3). It's suggested that setting `header("Connection: close");` could solve the issue.

The thing I'm not clear on is where to set connection close? Is that a header that should get sent along with the POST request from the app? Or something we should set on the backend every time an image upload completes?

Also, if you think this could be solved by something other than the above, let me know.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nothing yet. It's not frequent enough that it's a massive problem, but I'd definitely like to figure it out. Will come back here if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

After some research online, it maybe solved by inserting a small bit of code as explained by:

"This is an old post, but I had a random problem of UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL, and post my solution. The problem is that after 2/3 upload I obtained an error of UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL, without any interruption by the client.  My problem was related to the Keep-Alive server. I solved it by inserting at the end of the PHP script for uploading  header ("Connection: close");"